# VB 2010 INSERT INTO syntax error

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Hello Good Afternoon I have a program in VB.Net that will Input data 
from textboxes into Access Database here is sample image

[image]

This is the code I am using and it gives me an error

```
m = TextBox1.Text
b = "'" + TextBox2.Text + "'"
x = "'" + TextBox3.Text + "'"
d = TextBox4.Text
n = "'" + TextBox5.Text + "'"
Dim s2 As String
s2 = "insert into users2 ( num , name1 , pass , add , phone ) " & " values ( " + m + " , " + n + " , " + b + " , " + x + " , " + d + " ) "
Dim cmd2 As New OleDbCommand(s2, con)
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Looking forward that someone will enlighten my problem since its im starting to program.

TYSM for future help

Comment: can you give us the data type of your columns and an example of data to insert ?

Comment: I forgot to insert a pic sorry, I just added it.

Comment: If I were you I'd also use better variable names, like number, name,password, ...

Comment: Your code is a security hazard as it is an open door for SQL Injection attackes. Use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: I can't use parameterized queries . I'm working on a uni project and teacher asked to do it this way.

Comment: string inside a string inside a string OMG

Comment: Then your teacher should be fired.

Comment: If you want to easily find the error, you could put a breakpoint on your cmd2 line and debug, then copy paste your s2 string into your sql management / query tool and try to straighten out the problem from there.

Comment: can you provide the error message or screen capture of it

Comment: it simply says "insert into syntax error"

Answer (score -1):

1. You need to encapsulate values you want to insert into ''

.   "values('" + m + "', '" + ...

2 I don't understand & operator between two parts of query in the beginning

Comment: VB allows both & and + as string concatenation. It's best to use & as + can  under ambiguous cases cause the compiler to treat the operands as numbers and attempt to add them.

Comment: I think in this case the _&_ probably isn't needed. The OP could just code `) values (` if they were so inclined.